# Where statement searching for 2 values in any combination of multiple variables in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I am trying to search for a double condition using Proc SQl. 
I want to search for when 'TTT' AND 'RRR' exist in v1,v2,v3,v4...v10
so it can be that TTT is in V1 and RRR is in v10 or in V1 and V2. There are many combinations but I don't want to type each combination out obviously. 
At the same time I want to also use an OR statement to search for variables from v1-v10 that either contain ('TTT' AND 'RRR') OR ('GGG') alone. I've been searching around, thought maybe a case when would work but I don't think so and also I need to make it a PROC SQL.

I know the below code is wrong as it's a longer version but, just to get the jist of what I mean:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN &start. AND &end. 
AND ( ((V1 = 'TTT' and V2 ='RRR') OR (V1 = 'GGG')) OR ((V1 = 'TTT' and V3 ='RRR') OR (V1 = 'GGG')) OR ((V1 = 'TTT' and V4 ='RRR') OR (V1 = 'GGG')) ...)
```

Thanks, 
Much Appreciated!

---

UPDATED version based on @Tom's Answer

```
 data
diag_table;
input v1 $ v2 $ v3 $ v4 $ v5 $;
cards;
TTT . . RRR .
GGG . . . .
. RRR . . TTT
. . . . .
FFF . . . .
. . RRR1 . .
TTT . . GGG .
. RRR . GGG .
run;
proc print data=diag_table;
quit;

proc sql;
create table diag_found  as
select *
from diag_table
WHERE (whichc('TTT',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) and whichc('RRR',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)) or (whichc('GGG',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5));
quit;
proc print data=diag_found;
quit;
```

[image]

The only problem with this code is that it's also grabbing cases where the rows
contain GGG + RRR, and GGG + TTT
I tried adding parentheses around the two groups but it didn't change anything.

UPDATE:
@Tom and @Joe:

Yes, I guess I do mean an XOR with an AND inside.

So if A=TTT B=RRR C=GGG
(A AND B) XOR C

Either A+B combination OR C

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean "XOR" (exclusive or - EITHER TTT/RRR or GGG but not both)?

Comment: If you test for (A or B) then that will include those with both A and B and also those with A and not B and those with B and not A. That is basic logic. Can you explain what you actually want?  Make a truth table if you have to. What do you mean by GGG alone? Is that where there is only one variable populated and its value is GGG?  What if GGG appeared more than once?

Comment: @Tom, I replied with a picture and a more detailed explanation of what I mean in the update to the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe, I replied with a picture and a more detailed explanation of what I mean in the update to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `WHICHC()` function to do what you want.

```
where whichc('TTT',v1,v2) and whichc('RRR',v1,v2)
```

Note it is a little harder to use in SQL since you cannot use variable lists so you will need to explicitly list each variable name, `whichc('TTT',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)`, instead of just using a variable list,`whichc('TTT', of v1-v5)` , like you could in a data step.

Not sure what you mean by GGG alone.  But if by that you mean GGG without TTT or RRR then you could use logic like this.

```
where (whichc('TTT',v1,v2) and whichc('RRR',v1,v2))
   or (whichc('GGG',v1,v) and not (whichc('TTT',v1,v2) or whichc('RRR',v1,v2)))
```

Comment: WOW thank you! I had no clue about this function. I am not able to keep the code formatted correctly when I place it in this comment box, so can you look up above in the question box, it works for my purposes well enough once I add the OR but it also grabs rows if it's TTT & RRR, cases where one or more are in there. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need anything particularly complicated here; the key concept which you'll see in user2877959's answer as well as mine is to concatenate the strings into one long string, so you only need a single call (or in my case, three simple calls).  Easier in data step than in sql, but it will work either way.

I use CATX with a delimiter to make sure "RR" | "RTTT" does not match, also.  Then we just use FIND to find the string that matches.

```
data have;
  input (v1-v10) (:$3.);
  datalines;
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJ
KKK LLL MMM NNN OOO PPP QQQ RRR SSS TTT
UUU VVV WWW XXX YYY ZZZ AAA BBB CCC DDD
GGG TTT RRR AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF HHH
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
  select * from have
      WHERE ( 
           find(catx('|',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10),'RRR') and 
           find(catx('|',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10),'TTT')
          ) ne
          (find(catx('|',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10),'GGG') > 0
          )
    ;
quit;
```

Of course the view could process the WHERE clause if you wanted it to also.

I've modified the code to add the XOR combination; basically it either contains GGG or TTT+RRR but not GGG+TTT+RRR.  This works by simply comparing the two boolean results (note I add `>0` to the second to get it to evaluate to a true/false; the first will already evaluate to true/false thanks to `and`).

If you actually want GGG+RRR to be excluded, you'll have to add some additional criteria; you may simply be better off assigning the values of 'has RRR', 'has TTT', and 'has GGG' to three variables (either in a view, or in the PROC SQL SELECT query) and then evaluate those rather than having to do a bunch of find/whichn/etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! But I think I will go ahead with Tom's answer as it's concise and efficient.

Answer (score -2):

You could try regular expressions. Something in the line of this:

```
where prxmatch('/(TTT.*RRR|RRR.*TTT)|GGG/',cats(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10));
```

Comment: Hm ok I am familiar with regex but can you walk me through it perhaps? What is the backslash for? the parenthesis is grouping but does it act like an AND? and the asterisks and periods as well I am unsure. Thanks by the way!

Comment: I don't think this is actually correct; it would identify as true when v1='RR' and v2='RTTT', which isn't in the criteria.  It also needs more detailed explanation than just code.

Comment: @Joe Yes, I know. Hence why I said _"something in the lines of"_. You would of course need to improve it like, say, `where prxmatch('/#TTT#(.+#)?RRR#|#RRR#(.+#)?TTT#|#GGG#/',cat('#',catx('#',v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10),'#'));`. Obviously, I assume `TTT`, `RRR` and `GGG` are not the _actual values he is looking for. Up to him to use my answer if he likes and tailor it to his needs.

Comment: @hope288 slashes are standard notation to mark the start and end of the regex pattern. The grouping parentheses weren't needed in this case (edited). The pipe `|` is an 'OR'. The dot matches any character and the star means _'zero or more of'_. Whether my answer is of use to you in this case, I invite you to look into regular expressions. It's a really powerful tool.

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely an option that I will think of to use in the future.